# Multiple Dynamic Array with conditional in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I have two arrays and I would like to make one conditional on the other. ARRAY1 contains binary flags (0 or 1) and I would like to make the second array be blank if the contents in ARRAY1[i] is 0. ARRAY1 and ARRAY2 have the same number of elements.

```
data test;

set test_data;

  array ARRAY1 &variable_flags;

  array ARRAY2  $ &variable_list &variable_list_initial_values;

  do i=1 to &variable_count;

   if ARRAY1[i]=0 then ARRAY2[i]="";

  end;

run;
```

My output works until it hits a 0 in ARRAY[i]. When that happens the column is blank after words. I end up with something like the attach image. Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Post your test data and example output as text in the question.  Pictures of data are hard to paste into the program editor.

Comment: I'm still confused. Suggest add sample input. And remove the macro stuff just to focus on the array question. Once you have it working without macro vars you can always add them back.

Answer (score 0):

The initial values for an array are set only once. They are not re-applied at the start of each iteration of the data step.  You could change your logic to have another array with the initial values.  Let's make some test data.

```
data test_data;
  input matt_flg @@ ;
cards;
1 1 0 0 1 1
;
```

Now let's set the value to either the default value or empty based on the value of the FLAG variable.

```
%let variable_flags=matt_flg;
%let variable_list=matt;
%let variable_list_initial_values="MATT";
%let variable_count=%sysfunc(countw(&variable_list));
%let maxlength=20 ;
data test;
  set test_data;
  array flags &variable_flags;
  array vars $&maxlength. &variable_list ;
  array default (&variable_count) $&maxlength. _temporary_ (&variable_list_initial_values);
  do i=1 to dim(vars);
    if flags(i) then vars(i)=default(i);
    else vars(i)=' ';
  end;
run;
```